# Dashboard links do not open

Tags: dashboard, links

The links on our donor dashboards do not open unless you right click and select "Open in a new tab".  I am referring to the "View" "Edit" & "Cancel" links that appear with recurring donations. I am using Wordpress 4.4.2 & Civi 4.6.14 this is a new website and Civi install so this is not something that was working and recently quit, it has never worked for me. Any suggestions so they function normally?[image: Screenshot of dashboard links]

Answer (score 2):

The guys at Ginko Street fixed it for me.  It was a conflict with my WordPress theme and Civi shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on your browser 'inspector' you will possibly see some js errors. It is possible that a wordpress plugin is conflicting with the code that generates the 'pop up'

Comment: In the screenshot with my question I have the browser inspector on. The bottom message shows up after you click the link. Is that I am looking for? If so, does this point to where to look for the problem?